# For loop not completing when accessing a key in JSON data ,during parsing

Tags: java, android, json, loops, parsing

I am trying to create an app for a youtube channel and for that I am using Youtube Data API v3. The data recieved is in JSON format and needs to be parsed to be displayed in recyclerview.

While parsing JSON I got stuck in a very unusual problem where my for loop is not completing its iteration over the JSON array. But this doesn't happen everytime. It only happens when I try to access a key called videoId. Although when I try to access other keys at the same nested level (like "publishedAt") as the videoId, the code runs fine.

I've been trying to get my head around this problem for the past 2 days but in vain. Please Help !!

Here is my code for MainActivity, VideoAdapter, Video (model data class) :

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    URL url = null;
    String resultString = null;
    RecyclerView rv;
    VideoAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Video> titles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_display);
        url = NetworkUtils.buildUrlFromUsername(Config.FOR_USERNAME);
        Log.i("ayusch", "url = " + url);
        new YoutubeQueryTask().execute(url);
        Log.i("ayusch", "After task");

    }

    public void formatJSON(String resultString) {
        new JSONParseTask().execute(resultString);
    }

    public class YoutubeQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL builtUrl = params[0];
            resultString = "no result";
            try {
                resultString = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromUrl(builtUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            formatJSON(s);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            adapter = new VideoAdapter(titles);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("ayusch", "" + adapter.getItemCount());
        }
    }


    public class JSONParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONObject itemsObj, thumbnailsObject, defaultObject, obj, snippetObj;
            ArrayList<Video> videoTitles = new ArrayList<>();
            String title, thumbnailUrl, description, videoId,date;
            try {
                itemsObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
                JSONArray itemsArray = itemsObj.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                    obj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    snippetObj = obj.getJSONObject("snippet");

                    title = snippetObj.getString("title");
                    thumbnailsObject = snippetObj.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    defaultObject = thumbnailsObject.getJSONObject("default");
                    thumbnailUrl = defaultObject.getString("url");
                    description = snippetObj.getString("description");

                    videoId = (obj.getJSONObject("id")).getString("videoId");
                    //date = snippetObj.getString("publishedAt");
                    videoTitles.add(new Video(title, thumbnailUrl, description, videoId));

                    Log.i("ayusch", "length of array = " + i);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            titles = videoTitles;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

VideoAdapter.java :

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.CustomHolder> {

    private int maxNumItems = 25;
    ArrayList<Video> titles;

    public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        CustomHolder holder = new CustomHolder(root, parent.getContext());
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_title.setText((titles.get(position).title));
        String url = titles.get(position).thumbnailUrl;
        Picasso.with(holder.tv_title.getContext()).load(url).into(holder.iv_thumbnail);
        holder.tv_description.setText((titles.get(position)).description);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class CustomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_title,tv_description;
        ImageView iv_thumbnail;
        Context c;

        public CustomHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_title);
            iv_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_thumbnail);
            tv_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_description);
            c = context;
        }


    }
}
```

Video.java :

```
public class Video {
    String title;
    String thumbnailUrl;
    String description;
    String videoId;

    Video(String vidTitle, String url, String desc ,String vidId) {
        title = vidTitle;
        thumbnailUrl = url;
        description = desc;
        videoId = vidId;

    }
}
```

Here is some of the json (not validated , only a part of the entire data) :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/x-MGNU9lsGdyhXyip2D886I5NP8\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CBkQAA",
 "regionCode": "IN",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 28,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/uYSFXJP9T4MDWQg_zw335jVDIZw\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "SckdKFwLA_8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-30T09:45:26.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCYBeH5TdGbIQSKWoWFYUAYw",
    "title": "B.o.B - Airplanes ft. Hayley Williams [HINDI COVER] | Papa Pandey",
    "description": "This is a cover song made by me @Papa Pandey lyrics - @Papa Pandey like if u love this song original video link ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SckdKFwLA_8/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SckdKFwLA_8/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SckdKFwLA_8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Papa Pandey",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/uK0xksJsOifxE8jj28n8xRIM5h8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "T3bGsPaaj8M"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-25T16:41:28.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCYBeH5TdGbIQSKWoWFYUAYw",
    "title": "Tharki Roomie",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/T3bGsPaaj8M/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/T3bGsPaaj8M/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/T3bGsPaaj8M/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Papa Pandey",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
}
```

Any performance improvement suggestions are also welcome !! :)

Comment: There is a better way to parse a JSON using GSON.
You should try it.

Comment: I know, I searched around the net for good tutorials but couldn't find any. I can do it for plain JSONs but for accessing nested keys I don't know how. Can you suggest some good tutorials as I really want to learn GSON ?

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606594/choose-only-selected-json-value-and-save-in-sharedpreferences/42606793#42606793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"for loop is not completing" shouldn't happen unless you exit them or get an exception.

In your code I suspect you are getting an exception in this line:

```
videoId = (obj.getJSONObject("id")).getString("videoId");
```

I suggest you debug the code and see exactly what is happening (may some of the Json objects you are getting do not have `"id"` tag.

To resolve you can try this:

```
JSONObject idJSONObject = obj.getJSONObject("id");
if (idJSONObject != null) {
    if (idJSONObject.hasElement("videoId)) {
        videoId = idJSONObject.getString("videoId");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do this null check as well as my suggestion of seeing whether the videoId exists. Two checks are better then one :)

Comment: Thanks !!! You saved the day for me. Some of the JSON objects had playlistId insted of videoId.....Searched around the net for two days. Great help man !! :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly accessing

```
videoId = (obj.getJSONObject("id")).getString("videoId");
```

You should first check if

```
(obj.getJSONObject("id"))
```

has a videoId object in it. I believe you can do this by:

```
JSONObject idObj = obj.getJSONObject("id");
if (idObj != null && idObj.hasElement("videoId)) {
    videoId = idObj.getString("videoId");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for json parsing.

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.

Paste your JSON [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and get your POJO class generated and then call `new Gson.fromJson(json,Pojoclass.class)`  and its done.

Comment: It generates 9 classes !!!   I really want to learn GSON but couldn't find any good tutorials.

Comment: You have pretty complex JSON, thats why it generates so much classes. Try starting [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

Comment: This documentation is not for beginner level according to me. I checked it out earlier, it's straight away throwing code instead of explanation.